# Why are some of the delegate instances in the .NET framework named with the suffix thunk?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have been navigating through the ASP.NET MVC source code and I notice that in a lot of places, there are function parameters of type `Func<T>` that have been named with the suffix thunk. And I've been thunking why that might be?

As far I can remember, in the early days, I did come across the term *thunk* and understood it to mean a "port from one CPU architecture to another." So, if you had a 16-bit DLL, and you wanted to use it in a 32-bit environment, you'd have to create a thunk to marshal all those integers and doubles between the two platforms.

But what is the motivation behind naming these `Funcs` with such a name? For e.g. here is one such method.

A ctor of the `System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection` class.

```
internal FormCollection(ControllerBase controller, 
                        Func<NameValueCollection> validatedValuesThunk,
                        Func<NameValueCollection> unvalidatedValuesThunk)
{
    base.Add(((controller == null) 
          || 
         controller.ValidateRequest) 
         ? 
        validatedValuesThunk() 
        : 
        unvalidatedValuesThunk());
}
```

And here's another instance. This is a private field in the `ControllerActionInvoker` class.

```
private Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, 
             IEnumerable<Filter>> _getFiltersThunk;
```

There are loads of such methods in the MVC code.

Comment: I was tempted to down vote for overusing a pun. But once I thunk about it, it seemed a bit harsh.

Comment: It did feel a bit overused, I edited out one of the instances. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk):

> In computer programming, a thunk is a subroutine that is created,
>   often automatically, to assist a call to another subroutine. Thunks
>   are primarily used to represent an additional calculation that a
>   subroutine needs to execute, or to call a routine that does not
>   support the usual calling mechanism.

The use of "thunk" in the `FormCollection` method seems to fit this definition.

Comment: You're right. I was reading that article, too, just after I posted this question. I guess the word simply means, "indirection" where such an indirection may provide an additional service such as adaptation to the caller's environment, or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single canonical meaning for the word "thunk". In this instance, I think it simply refers to a function object. Personally, I don't use the word "thunk" in that way, but like I said, there's no commonly-agreed meaning for that word.